# De-code JSON data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have this PHP code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=1707%20Sixes%20Rd%20,%20Prince%20Frederick%20,%20MD,%2020678&destinations=2000%20Medical%20Pkwy%20,%20Annapolis%20,%20MD,%2021401&mode=driving&units=imperial');

$details = json_decode($json, TRUE);
?>
```

JSON data is as below, stored in $details

```
{
"destination_addresses" : [ "Annapolis, MD 21401, USA" ],
"origin_addresses" : [ "Prince Frederick, MD 20678, USA" ],
"rows" : [
  {
     "elements" : [
        {
           "distance" : {
              "text" : "37.8 mi",
              "value" : 60775
           },
           "duration" : {
              "text" : "51 mins",
              "value" : 3039
           },
           "status" : "OK"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"status" : "OK"
}
```

I want to extract "37.8 mi" from it. Can anybody help?

Comment: Not exactly the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$array = json_decode($details, true);
$distance = $array['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];
```